# Prove that a Wiener process with a point of attraction is a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

> Suppose $\{W(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$ is a Wiener process with $W(t) \sim N(0, σ^2 t)$ and $a > 0$ a constant. Define$$
> Z(t) = 
> \begin{cases}
> W(t); & \sup\limits_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} W(s) < a\\
> a; & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}.
> $$
>   Prove that $\{Z(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$ is a Markov process.

Basically the definition of $\{Z(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$ means that once $W(t)$ hits the point $a$, all $Z(t)$ from this instant on becomes $a$, namely "attracted" by this point.

The hint is to prove that $\{Z(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$ has independent increments. I know that $\{W(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$ has independent increments, but in the definition of $\{Z(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$, it seems that each $Z(t)$ is "related" to all $W(s)$ before $t$, thus all $Z(s)$ before $t$. So how to prove the independence of the increments of $\{Z(t) \mid t \geqslant 0\}$?

Comment: I have some doubts that the process has independent increments. Do you know about the strong Markov property (of Brownian motion)?

Comment: @saz We haven't learned strong Markov property yet. If the hint is incorrect, is it possible to prove directly?